# How to restrict users to vote only once without registration in android app?

Tags: android

I am new to android development so I need a little help.
In my app users can vote for posts but I don't want to make them register because app is very simple and that would be overkill. I want some another way to restrict users so they vote just once. If the method is not very accurate I don't care. In web development it's usually done using IP, is it the same for mobile apps?
Appreciate your help very much.

Comment: IMEI number? for dual sims you need to check either of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every mobile device has a unique id which is called device id. you can use device id to restrict users or another option is to get the device MAC address of the device. MAC address is also unique so you can easily use it restrict users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IP but for mobile users that won't work very well because their IP's are always changing. An easy way to do it would be to generate a guid in the app, and save it somewhere permanent (like the app settings). Then whenever you need to id the user just submit that guid to your webservice or whatever you are using. This is an anonymous id that you can then check against etc..